# Autocomplete not working properly

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, search

I am new for java script.My requirement as same like below code this code working fine, but not getting exact output. What do I need to change please can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance!

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="DemoAutoComplete" showHeader="false">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

    <script>

        if(typeof jQuery != 'undefined'){
           $j =jQuery.noConflict();
       }
         $j(function() {            
             $j("input.auto001").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response){
                    getMyData(response ,request.term);
                },
                select: function(event, ui){
                    $j("input.auto001").val(ui.item.value);
                    $j('input.auto002').val(ui.item.id);
                    refresh();                    
                    return false;
                }            
            });            

        });



        function getMyData(response,param){
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.DemoAutoComplete.getAccounts}',
                param, 
                function(result, event){
                    if (event.status) {                        
                        var objList = [];
                        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                            var obj = new Object();
                            obj.label = result[i].Name;
                            obj.value = result[i].Name;
                            obj.id = result[i].Id;
                            objList.push(obj);
                        }
                        response(objList);
                    }else {
                        alert(event.message);
                    }
                }, 
                {escape: true}
            );
        }
</script>

    <apex:form id="mainForm">    
        <div class="filterOverview">
            <div class="bFilterView">
                <table border="0">                    
                    <tr>    
                        <td>Choose an account</td>                    
                        <td>
                            <div class="ui-widget">
                                <apex:inputText id="x_val" styleClass="auto001" value="{!accName}" />
                                <apex:inputText id="auto002" value="{!accId}" styleClass="auto002" style="visibility:hidden"/>                                
                            </div>
                        </td>                
                    </tr>                
                    <tr>    
                        <td>selected Id</td>                    
                        <td>
                            <apex:actionfunction name="refresh" action="{!Refresh}" rerender="pn1"/>
                            <apex:outputPanel id="pn1">
                                <apex:outputText id="x_id" value="{!accId}" />
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </td>                
                    </tr>                                
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class DemoAutoComplete {
    public String accName{get;set;}
    public Id accId{get;set;}

    public DemoAutoComplete(){

    }
    public PageReference refresh(){
        return null;
    }
    @RemoteAction
    public static list<Account> getAccounts(string s){
        list<Account>accList = new list<Account>();
        if(s != ''){
            String query = 'select id, name from account where Name like \'' + s + '%\'';
            accList = database.query(query);
        }    
        return accList;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you explain more about the problem i.e. what exactly do you mean by "not getting exact output"?

Comment: I need to display autocomplete related records which is given in textbox. The thing is if you enter any text called Keith it display the related alphabet using autocomplete functionality. Please help me Keith.